# How to remove button with jquery

Tags: jquery, button

First I add dynamically button

```js
var r = $('<input type="button" name="button1"/>');
$("#c").append(r);
```

```html
<div id="c"></div>
```

But after that I don't know how to remove r.

Comment: `$('input[name="button1"]').remove()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny suggested the best, as well as you can use `$("#c").empty(); ` also :)

Answer (score 1):

Use  `$('#c input[name="button1"]').remove();`

Read about [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 0):

use [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function of jQuery,

```
$("input[name='button1']").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following function to reduce the overhead and be more specific because your already assigned to an variable `r`

`r.remove()`

Comment: r variable is not global , so you cant simply use it to remove it

Comment: You're right if you assumed it is not global and Dimac is going to use outside the scope of variable `r`.  Dimac I guess any of us are possible to get your button out. Just try the simplest and fastest one you can :)